FIPS Errors on Azure Container Apps Backend Containers Despite No Code Changes
I have three containers running on Azure Container Apps—two backend containers and one frontend container. The frontend container is running fine, but I'm encountering issues with the backend containers. Everything was working perfectly for the past five months, and there have been no code changes. However, starting today, the backend containers stopped working and are throwing the following errors in the container logs:
crypto/fips/fips.c:154: OpenSSL internal error: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE
...
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: XXXX
crypto/fips/fips.c:154: OpenSSL internal error: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE
It appears to be related to FIPS. I suspect that Microsoft might have pushed a new update that enabled FIPS on the container apps. I tried to disable FIPS from the Container Apps console, but it doesn’t let me. I also updated my Dockerfile to include ENV OPENSSL_FORCE_FIPS_MODE 0, but the issue persists.
I'm running out of options and would appreciate any pointers or advice on how to resolve this issue.
I am using Python Flask for backend and also tried updating my all the libraries to latest version.

Please add the exact versions of the software you're using, especially the exact version of OpenSSL.

This is happening to me on Ubuntu noble 24.04, which ships with OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024. It is not happening on current alpine:latest, which runs OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024. Except the error I see complains about a missing fips.so.

This fails in the same way for me on Ubuntu oriole, which ships OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024 just like alpine.

And setting OPENSSL_FORCE_FIPS_MODE=0 works for me. I set it in the container app's container template rather than in the image, for whatever that's worth.

Thank you @DanekDuvall. I dont have access to the container template. However, I can update and deploy my docker file.  Would that work ?

I don't know, @ALphaCS. I would expect so, but it looks like you tried that already, and it didn't work? I'm not sure why it would be different if you tried it again. If you can exec into the container (az containerapps exec), make sure the variable is set in the environment, and also try running openssl ciphers. At least, that was the test I was using; since we got different errors, I can't be sure what worked for me will work for you.

Those are related: https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/1cwkxuf/azuregov_fips_mode_on_by_default_and_cannot_be/ and
https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python/issues/2115

Can you run sysctl crypto.fips_enabled on your machine (it should return 0 or 1) (or in your container).

This has been a known recent issue where Azure Container Apps enabled FIPs for their resources in all US regions as part of compliance. This update caused certain algorithms to be blocked at the kernel level. Apps that are using non-FIPs compliant algorithms were impacted.
The update has been rolled back and FIPs is now disabled for all regions so issues should be resolved. You no longer need to apply any environment variables to your app, if you already have, it might cause the issue to persist, once removed everything should be back to normal.

Azure Container Apps (ACA) have been enabling FIPS in their us based regions. Current mitigation is to add OPENSSL_FORCE_FIPS_MODE=0 in your environment variable or docker file.
If this does not help, you can reach out to acasupport@microsoft.com.
Update: ACA is rolling back their FIPs update
